# Listing all files in a folder, only first character of file name gets printed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm trying to access all images in a designated folder, get their names, and then pass them for further processing (getting their pixel values, to be precise, but this isn't relevant now). The following test code should list the name of every image found, however, for some reason it only lists the first letter for each image.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
WIN32_FIND_DATA search_data;

memset(&search_data, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(L"images\\*.jpg", &search_data);

while(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
  printf("Found file: %s\r\n", search_data.cFileName);

  if(FindNextFile(handle, &search_data) == FALSE)
    break;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is compiled for Unicode, but your printf format string is expecting an ASCII string.  Change the %s to %S.

Comment: I love spending half an hour on this kind of blunders... Thanks a lot, sir.

Comment: No worries - we've all been there!